# Dropwizard WARN statements: org.reflections.Reflections: could not get type for name javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter from any class loader

Tags: java, scala, jersey, sbt, dropwizard

I'm building a Dropwizard application using Dropwizard `1.3.5`.  I'm wondering if it's related to my assembly merge strategy (which I already had to modify to make sure a Hibernate dependency was included in the fat jar).  Here is my `sbt-assembly` config:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("application.conf") => MergeStrategy.concat
      case PathList("META-INF", "services", _*) => MergeStrategy.first
      case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

For reference here is the full stacktrace:

```
! java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter
! at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
! at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
! at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
! at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:388)
! ... 69 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not get type for name javax.servlet.jsp.JspWriter
! at org.reflections.ReflectionUtils.forName(ReflectionUtils.java:390)
! at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:381)
! at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
! at io.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig.classes(BeanConfig.java:276)
! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.BaseApiListingResource.scan(BaseApiListingResource.java:59)
! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.BaseApiListingResource.process(BaseApiListingResource.java:120)
! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.BaseApiListingResource.getListingJsonResponse(BaseApiListingResource.java:155)
! at io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.getListing(ApiListingResource.java:32)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1655)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1642)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:239)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:724)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:67)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception is from dropwizard-swagger plugin.
https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger/issues/133

> Dropwizard version 1.3.9
> Dropwizard-swagger version 1.3.9-1
>
> But the issue is that dropwizard-swagger searches for classes that are not present when using the shadow plugin (https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) .
>
> dropwizard-swagger searches for a bunch of classes that are not present.

upgrade to latest version should fix the issue.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)